# CakePHP issues with .htaccess file on site5 server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, cakephp

Building a CakePHP website for a client, it runs perfectly on my local environment, and when being tested on my server. However, when I transferred it to the client's site5 server it returned nothing but 404 errors.

After some modifications to the .htaccess files I was able to get the default landing page working fine:
`http://174.120.222.98/~sty/`

The issue I have, is that only the default landing page can be found. All of the sub-pages are still returning 404 errors (example: "NEW STUDENTS" Green-background link in NavBar).

I've changed the root/.htaccess file to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /~sty
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

without `RewriteBase /~sty` The default landing page is a 404.

I've changed root/app/.htaccess file to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

Without this change, none of the files in webroot loaded (images/styles/js).

Those two files alone seem to be all I need for the default page, I can even remove the root/app/.htaccess file and the landing page looks great.  So I'm assuming the app file is the one that will govern my sub-pages.  Nothing I've done to it seems to work, it is currently set to:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteBase /~sty
   RewriteRule    ^$ webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I've tried to `RewriteBase` with `\`, `\~sty`, `\~sty\app` and without the line so far none of my changes seem to work.

Help me StackOverflow, you're my only hope.

Comment: Enable the rewrite log, and see for yourself what’s going on.

Comment: I liked the idea of looking at the rewrite log, but never was able to acquire access to it. 

I have not "solved" the issue, but we have redirected the subdomain dev. to the ~sty directory, which allows the default CakePHP .htaccess files to work.

Answer (score 0):

mod_rewrite is not enabled on your server so you have to handle this with .htaccess file in your **root directory**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule    ^$ app/webroot/    [L]
   RewriteRule    (.*) app/webroot/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

and another .htaccess in your **app** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

and another one in your **webroot** folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```